# How to request NASMT Q700 QNAP linux hard disk smart states using the ssh interface?

Tags: linux, ssh, qnap

I use a NASMT Q700 QNAP NAS. For remote monitoring purposes i want to read some values and save them into a database.

Since the web-interface is very complex and full of javascript, i can not scrape it. So I tried to connect to the NAS with SSH.

Which is great, because SSH is one of the methods, that i can connect with automatically with c# and I get back text that I can parse.

The installed Linux system on the box is a :

Linux NASMT 2.6.33.2 #1 Fri Mar 7 11:55:22 CST 2014 armv5tel unknown

I tried to reach my goal:

- man is not installed.
- smartctl is not installed. (Google told me to try this out)
- I went into the /bin and /usr/bin directories and tried everything suspecious. There seems to be a program called nasutil installed. Only that it is not very self documenting. Various calls with different parameters did not work, i always get the same answer:

> nasutil multi-call binary
>      [function] [arguments]...
>
> Current defined functions:
>              init_nas_cache, init_admin_group, set_file_owner, chk_flash, reset_all, chk10198, get_trusted_domain, update_krb5_ticket
>              rescan_hd, check_e2key, burn_e2key, cnt_phy_nic, http_link, ip_filter, hdusb_copy, ims, qpkg, gen_upnp_desc, scanafpdb
>      eset_system, umount_all_vdd, sss_convert, httpd_init, get_hwsn, get_suid, setsum, getsum, rsyslog_util, radius_util, send_alert_mail, rsync_util
>              acl_cmd check_ldap clean_reset_pwd network_boot_rescan

I used google on this one but could not find anything useful.

I am looking for a command on this linux system without smartctl to give me a list of the installed hard drives with their SMART status.

Has anyone an idea?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, I was able to find the answer using email and contacts at Fujitsu.

The answer was simple as can be:

```
# get_hd_smartinfo -d 1 
1 is disk 1.  Replace with 2 if want to check disk 2.
```

I did not test it yet, as soon as I have, i'll accept the answer for everyone to see.

Comment: works here example output:  `[~] # get_hd_smartinfo -d 1
001 Raw_Read_Error_Rate          263985   199 197 051 OK
003 Spin_Up_Time                 4316     173 172 021 OK
004 Start_Stop_Count             4327     096 096 000 OK
005 Reallocated_Sector_Ct        1171     143 143 140 ABNORMAL

`